# Download localized files from server - ios programming

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsbundle

For localized files, for example, localizedthis.png, the path for this file can be retrieved using

```
[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:forLocalization:].
```

The question is, if we download the files from server and store them in "Documents" folder, is there any equivalent way to do something similar to above method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundles are essentially just directories with a specific structure. So you could put the localized files that you download into a directory like `Documents/MyBundle/Contents/Resources/fr.lproj/` (for French) and instead of `[NSBundle mainBundle]`, you'd use `[NSBundle bundleWithPath:...]`.